# Activity handler

Tags: java, android, event-handling, handler

I’m trying to intercept all keyevents and motionevents is it possible to assign a new handler for my activity where in that new handler before the events get processed they are logged first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In order for the application to know that an action has been performed, it has to be logged. The log then triggers the event call.